# Migrating from access to mySQL trap null values and replace

Tags: mysql, null, ms-access-2013, data-migration

I am using MySQL Workbench 6.2CE to migrate an Access (.accdb) database to MySQL. The process sets all keyfields to Not Null (which is fine since none are). The data migration then fails because there are NULLs scattered across the Access Database in various fields; all make business sense (e.g. a date might be unknown but be added later).

I would like advice on how best to address this problem without introducing problems later. Various options might include...

Is there some way of interrupting the Workbench Migration to allow for NULLs; is there a way to replace all NULLs in the Access Database (and if so with what: e.g. what to use for an empty date or blank string)?

Or is there a simpler and more obvious solution?

Comment: What might various option include?

Comment: I was unable to recreate your issue. I migrated a table from Access to MySQL using MySQL Workbench Community 6.2.5.0 and it migrated NULL values without complaint. Please [edit] your question to better explain how the NULL values in your table(s) are causing the problem. (e.g. What exactly do you mean by "all keyfields"?)

Comment: The options might include those suggested in the following paragraph.

Comment: Thank you Gord Thompson: I have identified my problem as several foreign-key fields that are defined as required but which over the years have been populated with NULLs. The schema, quite correctly says NULL not allowed but the Access database contains NULLs.